# conda activate disables prompt coloring

Tags: command-prompt

I've been enjoying my PS1 prompt:

```bash
export PS1="\[\033[38;5;1m\](${CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV##*/})\[$(tput sgr0)\] \h:\[\033[38;5;4m\]\w\[$(tput sgr0)\] \[\033[38;5;3m\]\$(git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/(\1)/')\[$(tput sgr0)\]\n\[\033[38;5;2m\]\t\[$(tput sgr0)\] \$\[$(tput sgr0)\] "
```

that gives me

```bash
(conda_env) hostname:current_directory (git_branch)
time $
```

At startup, `(conda_env)` is red, as specified and expected. But when I do `conda activate my_new_env`, the red color is gone.

How do I fix this?

Comment: maybe this can help?
https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/11885

Comment: Did running `conda init bash` work for you as the answer in the github link above from @aramcpp?